# Random function each time called in c++

Tags: c++, function, random

I'm new in C++, I used only a few hours.

I would like to create a function that populates an array/vector with random values between 1 to 255 (for randomized IP addresses).

I created this:

```
vector<int> gen_ip_tuple(){

    int sh_rand;
    vector<int> vect_tuple;
    srand(time(NULL));  // initialize random seed
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        sh_rand = rand() % 255 + 1;     // between 1 to 255
        cout << sh_rand << endl;
        vect_tuple.push_back(sh_rand);
    }   
    return vect_tuple;
}
```

It works well if it is called one time.

But if I call this function several times, it will produce the same 4-tuple result each time.

I don't understand because I use `srand(time(NULL))` to have a random seed.

This seed is set in the function, so it must be new each time.

---

In summary:

- Each time the program rerun the 4-tuple is random (different from previous run)

  ```
  first run = {67,127,115,45}
  second run ={157,142,16,93}
  ```
- Each time the function is called, it produces the same result.

  ```
  first call = {157,142,16,93}
  second call ={157,142,16,93}
                   ....
  ```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: The writeup is good, but I'm downvoting because this question is so frequently asked that I already knew having seen only "random function" and "each time." Google would have saved a lot of trouble.

Comment: You need to use srand() just once in your program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"srand(time(NULL)) to have a random seed" <-- this only gives you a different seed if the `time(NULL)` value has changed, which only happens once a second.  If you call your function 4 times intra-second, you get four identical result sets.

You should move the `srand()` setup out of `gen_ip_tuple`, probably into your `main()` function.  It's not intended for different parts of the program to keep calling `srand()`.

### EDIT

> I change srand(time(NULL)); to srand(time(NULL)+rand()); It works well. Thanks guys. - @user1778354

As randomness goes, that's a seriously broken approach.  It invalidates the period for which `rand()` is otherwise guaranteed not to repeat (2^32 on popular platforms), and consequently `time(NULL) + rand()` will happen to evaluate to an already-used `srand()` seed much sooner.  Even if `rand()` was as random as a cryptographic hash - and it's far from it - risk would be as per the "birthday problem", see http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/ - i.e. ~10% after 25000 calls, 50% after 50000 calls, 90% after 150000 calls.

I don't know how many times your program will call `gen_ip_tuple`, or how seriously you need it random, but there's no benefit and serious issues with your approach.

Comment: I change srand(time(NULL));
  to srand(time(NULL)+rand());

It works well. Thanks guys.

Comment: @user1778354 Read up on how random number generators actually work, you shouldn't call `srand()` multiple times. Do the initialization one time in your `main`, as Tony D suggested.